# Dynamically show dropdown select list to improve performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page where users edit a grid of data that contains up to 400 form fields. Think inline editing of a table.

The problem is where most of the form fields are `select` dropdowns, some of which can contain up to 1,000 options.

This is causing browsers to use a *lot* of memory, and to run far too slowly.

Is there some way to improve performance here, perhaps by dynamically filling the dropdown every time it's clicked, and clearing all but the selected option when leaving the dropdown?

Comment: you could create one dropdown and move it around with JS to make it look like it's a dropdown on each one. or you could have the options in the list loaded dynamically as they type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally wouldn't advise clearing all other options from a select dropdown when a user selects one, in case they select the wrong one.

If you still would like to do this, use something similar to the following, to achieve it:

HTML Example

```
<select id="long_select">
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">test2</option>
  <option value="3">test3</option>
  <option value="4">test4</option>
  <option value="5">test5</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript Example

```
// ITERATE THROUGH ALL SLEECTS ON THE PAGE, ADDING A FUNCTION TO THEIR 'onchange' EVENT HANDLER, WHICH WILL EXECUTE WHEN THE USER CHANGES THE SELECTS OPTION
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
var len = selects.length;
while(len--)
{
    selects[len].onchange = select_delete;
}

// THIS FUNCTION CAPTURES THE SELECTED OPTION, CLEARS ALL OPTIONS AND APPENDS THE SELECTED OPTION TO THE SELECT'S OPTIONS COLLECTION, LEAVING ONLY ONE OPTION
function select_delete()
{
    var item = this[this.selectedIndex];
    this.options.length = 0;
    this.appendChild(item);
}
```

And here's a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93o0qphv/1/

EDIT:

To dynamically populate select elements, you can create new option element, set it's 'text' and 'value' properties, and add it to the desired select.

HTML

```
<select id="first_select"></select>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
// POINTER TO DESIRED SELECT
var select = document.getElementById('first_select');

// ARRAY HOLDING ONE OBJECT PER OPTION
var options_array = [{"textvar":"Option 1","valuevar":1},{"textvar":"Second option","valuevar":2}];

// ITERATE THROUGH ARRAY, USING EACH OBJECTS 'textvar' AND 'valuevar' AS THE NEW OPTIONS 'text' AND 'value' PROPERITES, THEN ADD NEW OPTION TO THE SELECT
for(var c=0;c<options_array.length;c++)
{
    var new_option = document.createElement('option');
    new_option.text = options_array[c].textvar;
    new_option.value = options_array[c].valuevar;
    select.appendChild(new_option);
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ShadeSpeed/gxxugp6v/

I hope this helps!

Dan.

Comment: This handles what to do once a user has selected something, but I also need to dynamically populate the select in the first place, to avoid massive HTML documents due to repeating the same options for many `select`s in the grid

Comment: I've edited the answer to show how to dynamically add option elements to select elements.

Comment: I used this as the basis of a solution, which results in a much smaller DOM and therefore a much more responsive browser!

Comment: That's brilliant news! Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something similar before.

One of your options is to AJAX load options for select boxes that are visible on the page at the current moment. So something like this: ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ouhs7398/1/) for if the code snippet doesn't work)

```js
function checkScroll(el) {
    var top_of_object = el.offset().top;
    var top_of_window = $(window).scrollTop();
    var bottom_of_object = el.offset().top + el.outerHeight();
    var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    if ((top_of_object > top_of_window && bottom_of_object < bottom_of_window) && el.is(':empty')) { // If the element is in view and it's empty
        el.load('ajax/MyURL?Select=thisSelect'); //Run ajax call to populate the element
    } else if (top_of_object < top_of_window || bottom_of_object > bottom_of_window) {
        el.empty(); // Empty elements not in view
    }
}
function fireScroll() {
    $('select').each( function() { //Loop through all selects
        checkScroll($(this));
    });
}
var timer;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    timer && clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(fireScroll, 100); // Make it only fire when you stop scrolling
});
fireScroll();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select><select></select>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<select></select><select></select>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<select></select><select></select>
```

You AJAX call would then just need to return a string that was something like `<option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option><option>MyOption</option>`

Comment: An interesting approach, but this will still result in a massive DOM after scrolling, due to so many dropdowns being populated.

Comment: Hundreds, and each can have hundreds of options

Comment: Fair enough then. I've used this method on things that tend to take up a lot more real estate on the page so it drastically reduces the initial page load time. I guess that doesn't quite work with a whole screen worth of select boxes ;).