# HTML Top Bar fixed and rescalling when scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I want to make my topbar not only fixed when scrolling, but also decreasing its size in height. 
So when i scroll down, i know how to make it fixed, but i wanna know how to improve site's visibility by rescaling its height.

Example: http://www.kriesi.at/themedemo/?theme=enfold-overview

I tried to search for the solution but its only about the fixed topbar, but not about its size.

Comment: check this solution http://callmenick.com/post/animated-resizing-header-on-scroll

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to the `scroll event` - not the best solution regarding to performance, but a quick and easy to use solution for now.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(window).height()-80)) {
    $('.navigation').addClass('nav--closed')// > 100px from top - show div
}
else {
    $('.navigation').removeClass('nav--closed')// > 100px from top - show div
    // <= 100px from top - hide div
}
});
```

and the css for this would be:

```
.navigation {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 8em;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: black;
    transform: translate3D(0,0,0);
    transition:height 0.4s ease-in-out;
    color: white;
}

.navigation.nav--closed{
            background-color: $colorWhite;
            height: 2em;
}
```

take a look at this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c4ma1avr/2/) it should be self explaining.

besides `scroll` you might try something with **requestAnimationFrame** which is faster and more performant!
[RAF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751539/dynamically-show-dropdown-select-list-to-improve-performance/29793370#29793370) to improve performance for scrolling :).

Comment: well you should rather work with `$.debounce` instead of `setTimeout()` but looks promising tho